# Use a useRef value to update a state value in React (Object is possibly null)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having an issue with `useRef`, where I am getting "object is possibly null" when trying to use it to set a stateful object.

```
const jselectRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null)
const [defaultHeight, setDefaultHeight] = useState<number>(0)
useEffect(() => {
    if (jselectRef.current !== null) {
        setDefaultHeight(jselectRef.current.offsetParent.clientHeight)
    }
}, [])
return (
    <>
        <button
            ref={jselectRef}
            style={{
                height: dropdownOpen ? defaultHeight * 10 : defaultHeight
            }}
        >
            <div className="jselect__current" style={{
                height: defaultHeight
            }}>
            </div>
        </button>
    </>
```

[image]

Normally, I would just change `useState<number>` to `useState<number | undefined`, then add a `?` to the reference as so:
[image]

But now I get "Object is possibly undefined" wherever I use the variable. The thing is, in `useEffect` I have a nullcheck there, so the value being null literally isn't possible. It's either 0 (default) or it gets it's value from the ref.

I suppose I could use an if statement to check if it's undefined every time I use it, but is that really the best way? That seems like too much technical burden for TypeScript sake. Is there a way to accomplish this with TypeScript?

Comment: [Here's a link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to a feature of TypeScript that will solve your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) can be `null` by spec.

So you need to either:

check that it isn't null:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (jselectRef.current?.offsetParent !== null) {
        setDefaultHeight(jselectRef.current.offsetParent.clientHeight)
    }
}, [])
```

or default to a numeric value:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (jselectRef.current) {
        setDefaultHeight(jselectRef.current.offsetParent?.clientHeight ?? 0)
    }
}, [])
```